# Canon printer can scan, copy, but cannot print from computer

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, printer

I had this issue since I upgraded my PC tower and made a clean W10 install on it. Everything was working fine before that. Now The scanner is detected, and respond normally, the machine can scan and print a copy on itself, but only the scanner is detected from the PC in the devices manager.

I tried Canon drivers, none will install until the end, they stop after "device found, please wait until the end of the installation" then cycle over "Device not detected, please connect the USB cable to the printer" etc (I reconnect the printer, the utility detect it, freeze for 15 min, then again not detected)

tried others answers found here => w + R => printermanagement.msc doesnt exist on my windows.

Drivers seems fines when I uninstall them and then reconnect the printer, windows auto install I guess but only the scanner.

Now I've tried manual install on virtual USB port, so the printer now appear on the list, but the error showed => 'data cant be send to printer due to current status of the printer. Check that printer is connected, try reboot etc etc'

Nobody ever mentionned anywhere the USB cable, which I think is related to my issue here, but I've also tried to switch and even bought a new one without success.

The printer is a Canon MG2550S.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following steps:

1. Clear the print spooler:

> Run cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> Type net stop spooler then press “Enter“.
>
> Type del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers* /Q then press “Enter“.
>
> Type net start spooler then press “Enter“.

2. In Control Panel, Programs and Features, remove the Canon applications.
3. In Control Panel, Devices and Printers, Drivers Tab, remove the Canon Drivers.

Restart the computer.

Now go back to Devices and Printers:

Add a Printer and select your Canon Printer  (You will need it plugged in by USB before trying to Add)

Allow it to install and test printing.

If the printer is still giving issues, try the Windows 10 Driver from this page.

https://www.canondriversoftware.com/canon-pixma-mg2550s-driver/

> Operating Systems:
>
> Windows 10 (64bit)
>
> Download / Installation Procedures
>
> Download the driver only (not the full package)
>
> Canon PIXMA MG2550S Windows Driver Download – 47.2Mb

Do not uninstall anything at this point.

Try installing the basic driver.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Everything went fine in the process which I followed precisely. When got back in the devices and printers, printer MG2550 was already in there (win autoinstall as I mentionned) still only as a scanner though. Tried reinstall the canon drivers, same as earlier.

Comment: I amended my answer to provide a driver-only download (not full package).  Try installing the driver-only without uninstalling anything from the first step.

Comment: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN cant access canondriversoftware.com unfortunatly. I unselected everything except the driver in the canon utility I got though

Comment: I do not quite understand. Can you get the driver only using another computer>

Comment: One thing you might try as the complete process is repeatable:  Find a source where you can download the basic driver only (47 MB as I recall). Clear the print spooler, uninstall Canon apps and drivers (all apps, all drivers). Restart. now install just the basic driver newly downloaded from the Canon site.

Comment: I cannot access the website you linked. The website wont load, displaying the message I wrote above. It does appear on google search result, but cannot access. I've search for amny days another driver but the canon utility found ont he official support canon website is the only one I could found and I'm still convinced it is totally useless since windows autoload drivers as mentionned earlier. I also said in the utility I can select which element to install, and I choose the driver only. I've repeated another time the process, same result as described before and in the original question.

Comment: See if some one you know can download the driver. I just downloaded it here. Then give it to you and try that driver. The site is a Canon Site.

Comment: So I used a vpn to access the english?american? canon website, and I just downloaded the exact same utility I got earlier. Did all the process again, etc etc. EDIT this one.. actually worked after a few minutes into the step I described as freezing earlier. wtf...

Comment: So do I understand the printer is installed and working? The Canon site I posted will have a good driver.

Comment: You may wish to acknowledge my answer since I provided steps to clear out existing printers and a link to working drivers. I think I helped you with this.

Comment: indeed sorry I'm new, so the conclusion is european canon website provide a broken utility driver. Many thanks to you.

Comment: No problem - thank you for the update.